# Which part of the box model does the outline property belong to?

Tags: html, css

Which part of the box model does the outline property belong to? Is the outline css property part the margin?

Comment: Outlines is like a border, though it does not take up space and is drawn above the content.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Comment: outline is drawn about the border not content @LGSon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `outline` property is not part of the CSS Box Model.

> [**18.4 Dynamic outlines: the `outline`
>   property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/ui.html#dynamic-outlines)
>
> - Outlines do not take up any space.
> - The outline created with the outline properties is drawn "over" a box,
>     i.e., the outline is always on top, and does not influence the
>     position or size of the box, or of any other boxes.
> - Since the outline does not affect formatting (i.e., no space is left
>     for it in the box model), it may well overlap other elements on the
>     page.

Comment: so it's on top of margin?

Comment: On top of border box, per the spec (see link in my answer). Have you tested and seen differently?